# Regex code for month and year(only 2 digits)

Tags: regex, yearmonth

I'm setting up a bot flow in my live chat for my users. To retrieve some of their rental, we need to ask the last 4 digits of their credit card then expiration date.

Since I have an open text field for the user input, I've added a regex code, but I'm stuck on the second part.

The first bot question for the last 4 digits: `^\d{4}$`
this is working perfectly.

The second bot question should be the expiration date in this format: `MMYY` or `MM/YY` or `MM-YY`

I've created the first part of the regex code for the MM and limit from 1 to 12: `(0[1-9]|1[1,2])`

Then I've added the `-` or `/`. This is where I'm stuck:

1. I want to add an option without the `-` and `/`
2. I want to add the year format only `YY` (not `YYYY`) and limit it starting from `23` (2023) and going up to `40` (2040).

My current code isn't working:

```
(0[1-9]|1[1,2])(\/|-|)(0[1-9]|23[4,0]
```

Comment: Which language do you use? Maybe better to do it programmatically than using regex.

Comment: I can only use Regex. I'm setting up this botflow on FreshDesk, and allows me only "alphanumeric input (this leads to any entry from the user) or Custom entry with Regex format

Comment: `(\/|-|)` can be simplified to `[/-]?` The `?` means optional.

Comment: `[1,2]` should just be `[12]`. Yours allows a comma as the second digit of the month.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! Do you have any advice for the YY format from 23 to 40 only please?

Comment: Your regexp for the year makes no sense. What do you think `23[4,0]` means? It matches either `234`, `23,`, or `230`.

Comment: I think this works: `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-\/]?(2[3-9]|3[0-9]|40)`  https://regex101.com/r/3bbmbL/1

Comment: @GillesQuénot I assumed he wanted the capture groups so he could extract the month and year.  Plus, your answer below has a `)` and no opening bracket so I'm not sure it is right.  If he didn't want the capture groups he could use `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-\/]?(?:2[3-9]|3[0-9]|40)`

Answer (score 1):

### For 23 to 40, use:

```
\b(?:2[3-9]|3[0-9]|40)\b
```

### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qq7ANl/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture: |
| `2` | 2 |
| `[3-9]` | any character of: '3' to '9' |
| `|` | OR |
| `3` | 3 |
| `[0-9]` | any character of: '0' to '9' |
| `|` | OR |
| `40` | '40' |
| `)` | end of grouping |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |

for the delimiter, as Barmar said in comments, you can use:

```
[/-]?
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[/-]?` | any character of: '/', '-' (optional (matching the most amount possible)) |

### Finally

use:

```
\b(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]){2}[/-]?(?:2[3-9]|3[3-9]|40){2}\b
```

If you need capture groups, feel free to adapt a bit.

Comment: Thanks! So after correcting the code to (0[1-9]|1[12])([/-]?)\b2[3-9]|3[3-9]|40

It allows me only to input date from 23 to 29 for the YY, as soon as I write 12/30, it won't accept my entry. 

Also 12-25 or 1225 for example is not accepted, only the "/". Any input to correct this?

Comment: Fixed last regex, was a lost parenthesis

Comment: @CarySwoveland slapping, yes ^^ Fixed, thanks to report

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/]?(2[3-9]|3\d|40)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/TBTgpAUHBzQwgx).

`^` and `$` (start and end) ensure the *whole* input is valid.

`/` has no special meaning in regex so does not need escaping, so `[-/]?` matches the separator (if you're using say javascript, you'll need to escape the slash because slash is a *delimiter* in that language).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The second bot question should be the expiration date in this format: `MMYY` or `MM/YY` or `MM-YY`*
>
> *I've created the first part of the regex code for the MM and limit from 1 to 12: `(0[1-9]|1[1,2])` ..."*

The syntax `[1,2]` is incorrect, there are no commas, and the range should be `[0-2]`.

> *"... Then I've added the `-` or `/`. This is where I'm stuck:*
>
> *1.  I want to add an option without the `-` and `/`*
> *2. I want to add the year format only `YY` (not `YYYY`) and limit it starting from `23` (2023) and going up to `40` (2040). ..."*

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/-]?(?:2[3-9]|3\d|40)
```

Here is the *Wikipedia* article on *regular expressions*.

- *[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.